# How to use a rails route for a singular resource in my javascript ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

Currently I have the following (working) code:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/show_group_members.js.erb
...
var gid= $(this).data("id");
...
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
    url: "/groups/"+gid,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json", 
    ...
```

but I would like to use the routes for a single group resource, i.e.

```
group GET      /groups/:id(.:format)                      groups#show
```

So I am trying to use

```
    url: <%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.group_path %> + gid,
```

but I am getting

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"groups"} 
missing required keys: [:id]
(in /home/durrantm/.../linker/app/assets/javascripts/show_group_members.js.erb)
```

[Update]
The complication here is that the view content itself is generated by a .js.erb template so I still can't use group_path(group) in it.

How can I use the route in js when there is a resource ?

btw I also tried

```
url: <%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.group_path %>,
         data: { id: gid },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing it wrong. I would forget about placing Rails code into the js and pass the url with data. Thanks to this you separate your Rails code from JS and avoid issues during assets compilation (like what is the host when no request is made?).

```
# view
<span data-link-url="<%= group_path(group.id) %>"></span>

# js
var link = $(this).data("link-url");
...
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: link,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
...
```

Using `<a href="your_link_to_group_here">`

```
<%= link_to 'my link', group_path(group.id) %>

var link = $(this).attr('href');
```

Comment: +1 Thanks.  fwiw you have open `span` abut close `button`.  Maybe should be close `span` instead of close `button` ?

Comment: Also trying to see how this will work given that I actually have multiple id's, e.g. many groups on that page.  Thinking that I will need to use jquery relative addressing to grab that specific id from that span.

Comment: Maybe I just need to make sure the `data-link-url` `span` is within the `a` link so that `$(this).data("link-url")` can reference it.

Comment: Yea, sorry for this. Firstly i used button but then I changed my mind to use <span>. You can always reference <a href="link" though :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it, is to use [js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes).

Install the gem:

```
gem "js-routes"
```

Include it in your `application.js` file:

```
/*
= require js-routes
*/
```

Then you can do this:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/show_group_members.js
...
var gid= $(this).data("id");
...
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
    url: Routes.group_path(gid),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json", 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The routes helper still needs the `resource` to be passed to it, even if it's a singular resource. So, your route should look like

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.group_path(group)
```

`group` being the variable where you store your ruby object.

Although, personally, I prefer @konole 's approach.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the complication that the HTML is, itself generated by js (i.e. I get the list of links for the group when I click the 'members' link, via ajax.

So in the end I used:

```
    ...
    url: "<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.groups_path %>" + "/" + gid,
    ...
```

Comment: But isn't that `js.erb` view associated with a controller action? You can use controller variables `@` as in `html.erb` views.